# Are there any benefits of using Terraform in case when infrastructure is built of Docker containers

Tags: docker-compose, docker-swarm, terraform, xen, infrastructure

We have a private cloud based on XenServer. Software components are the docker containers running on dozen of VMs.

I'm new to Terraform and wonder are there any benefits of using it in comparison to docker-compose v3 (with built in support for swarm mode).

Answer (score 1):

There are some benefits of using terraform building docker based platform. Terraform has docker provider which uses the Docker API to manage the lifecycle of Docker containers. Because the Docker provider uses the Docker API, it is immediately compatible not only with single server Docker but Swarm and any additional Docker-compatible API hosts.

Comment: Here is the according [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/docker/index.html).